# Windows 64bit SQL 2005 CLR Install Mystery

Tags: sql-server-2005, clr, 32bit-64bit

My 32bit .NET application runs SQL 2005 Express SP3 and uses CLR. The install works fine on XP & Vista. The install fails on XP 64bit & Widows 7 64bit machines.

The error is in one of my SQL scripts that creates an Assembly:

**Error:**
“Execution of .NET Framework code is disabled. Set ‘CLR enabled’ configuration option and restart server. (5847)”

**Script Code:**
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyCode
FROM 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MyCode.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE

HOWEVER when I check the CLR it is enabled. In fact my very first script turns the CLR On and Trustworthy On.

So again, this **all works on 32bit machines** but not on 64bit.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WoW64 (x86 Express instance installed on x64 host OS) you need to restart the instance for the CLR enabled to take effect, see [clr enabled Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175193.aspx):

> WOW64 servers must be restarted before
>   the changes to this setting will take
>   effect. Restart is not required for
>   other server types.

Comment: WOW! This is a surprise. 

Do you know of a way to set CLR On before the install starts the server?

Thanks for the great info...

Comment: No way afaik. You need to install, and right after the install finishes, run sp_configure to enable clr, then recycle the MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS service via ServiceController.Stop()/Start()

Comment: Or you could install the x64 .msi of Express to start with.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this. I’ve spread this problem across many forums with no results. You’re quite the expert!

Comment: After I've been burned by this Wow64 restart issue for the thousanth time, I kinda learn it :)